# LongListSelector: Strange result when filtering items

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8, filtering, longlistselector

Here is my XAML code. Currently, `LongListSelector` is displaying two `TextBox`es; `City` and `Country`.

```
<DataTemplate x:Key="LongListSelectorItemTemplate">
    <ListBoxItem>
        <StackPanel Name="Address">
            <TextBlock Name="city" Text = "{Binding City}" />
            <TextBlock Name="country" Text="{Binding Country}"/>
        </StackPanel>
    </ListBoxItem>
</DataTemplate>

<TextBox Name="search"/>
```

There is a `SearchBox` and depending on the search text, I need to highlight the text in the `LongListSelector`, then filter out any other content. This is exactly how the People / PhoneBook application works in the device.

I have managed to get the highlighting / filtration working, however, the order of the items becomes very random in situations like the following:

```
London
UK

Delhi
India

NY
US

Paris
France
```

After the highlight, it becomes:

```
London
India

Paris
US

...
```

Here is my C# code so far:

```
void searchResults() {
    var filtereBlocks = RecurseChildren<StackPanel>(ListSelector)
        .Where(n => n.Name == "Address").ToList();

    foreach (var container in filtereBlocks) {
        bool ret1, ret2;
        TextBlock city = container.Children[0] as TextBlock,
               country = container.Children[1] as TextBlock;

        ret1 = Highlight(ref city, search.text); 
        ret2  = Highlight(ref country, search.text);
        if (!ret1 && !ret2) {
            city.visibility = System.Windows.Visibility.Collapsed;
            country.visibility = System.Windows.Visibility.Collapsed;
        }
    }
}

// Found on the Internet

IEnumerable<T> RecurseChildren<T>(DependencyObject root) where T : UIElement {
    if (root is T) {
        yield return root as T;
    }

    if (root != null) {
        var count = VisualTreeHelper.GetChildrenCount(root);
        for (var idx = 0; idx < count; idx++) {
            foreach (var child in RecurseChildren<T>(VisualTreeHelper.GetChild(root, idx))) {
                yield return child;
            }
        }
    }
}
```